# Setting ComplexType in MathLink

Tags: c#, .net, wolfram-mathematica, mathlink

I have another one. I tried to use `ml.ComplexType = System.Type.GetType("Complex");` in C# with the Mathematica MathLink, but when I tried to read the numbers with GetComplexArray, it threw an exception stating that I must use the method `IMathLink.SetComplexType()`, which does not appear to exist.

Is there any way to do this without parsing strings, since I can't for the life of me do that correctly?

Comment: Did you check (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/NETLink/ref/net/Wolfram.NETLink.IMathLink.ComplexType.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else's reference, I discovered the answer to this one on my own.

What you do is create a dummy instance of any class that has the necessary properties/methods (such as `System.Numerics.Complex`), here named `myVar`. Now assuming `ml` is an instance of `IKernelLink`, call

```
ml.ComplexType = myVar.GetType();
```

You can then use `ml.GetComplex()` or `ml.GetComplexArray()`.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for SetComplexType is here: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/NETLink/ref/SetComplexType.html.  You can also find this by pasting "NETLink/ref/SetComplexType" into the Mathematica documentation center.  Both these sources indicate that you must execute `Needs["NETLink`]" prior to use in Mathematica.

Comment: I'm trying to do this in C#. Do I send SetComplexType to MMA in MathLink?

Comment: While I thank you for your answer, it was for setting the type in Mathematica. I answered my own question for doing it entirely in C#.